# CSS reveal on hover HTML content

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm wanting to create some boxed content that reveals alternate content when hovered. I've found a few examples from others questions, and tried to utilise them to what I want, but not having much luck.

The perfect example of what I'm trying to achieve is the 3 hover buttons under the "Build a Smarter WordPress Site" (just below the fold) on http://www.copyblogger.com/.

I'm assuming the static state includes an icon/image & text below, and the hover state includes an icon/image, descriptive text, and a hyperlinked button.

This is exactly what I'm wanting to reproduce. Could anyone please provide an example of this so I can understand what I need to do?

Thanks.

Edit: I understand the code Copyblogger have used from what little I can retrieve through "Inspect Element". I'm not looking to use their code - as I cannot find all the connecting commands, but something that acts the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/f2AG4/). There are 3 or 4 ways to do this, but you just want someone to do it for you, so I wont go into those specifics. I wrote it mobile first and assuming you can use `box-sizing: border-box;` - so if you can't do that  - then you just add the proper widths and you'll be good to go.

### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="block-icon">

    <div class="block top-stuff">
        <div class="text-w">
            Top stuff
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block under-stuff">
        <div class="text-w">
            <h4>Under stuff</h4>
            <p>Some paragraph</p>
            <div class="button">Call to action</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</a>
```

### CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.block-icon {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    height: 10em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.block-icon .block {
    height: 100%;
    padding: .5em;
}

.block-icon .text-w {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.block-icon .text-w:after {
    content: "\0020";
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* this creates a second element so that they can align vertical middle to one another */
}

.top-stuff {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s linear;
}

.under-stuff {
    background-color: #eee;
}

a:hover .top-stuff {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .1s linear;
}

.button {
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}


@media (min-width: 500px) {

    .block-icon {
        width: 32%;
        margin-right: 2%;
    }

    .block-icon:nth-of-type(3) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

} /* end break-point */
```

Comment: Thanks Derek. I'm more than happy to learn the other ways of doing it. I just find it much easier to understand how it's done if I can see a working example with all the "moving parts" to put it together. This is exactly what I was after. Thank you for such a prompt reply. :)

Comment: There are a couple of things that might trip you up depending on how you go about it. Understanding relative and absolute positioning is the key. -- and dealing with heights can be tricky if you get different amounts of text in each box. Good luck!

Comment: Here's the boxes you've provided on the site. http://thesocialadviser.bazgardner.com/

I worked out the 4th box right margin, etc, only thing I'm not understanding now is why the blue bordered box changes size, and doesn't stay within the red border when in it's static state.

I have had to wrap the whole lot in their own div 'index' (?) to get the height correct on the page. But I don't think that is affecting it.

`#portal { position: relative; top: -45px; z-index: 1; }`

This is the code you gave me modified to suit: http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/f2AG4/

Comment: All good. Worked it out. Just trying to get the hover to not respond with the mouse below it. It's wanting to react to it even though I'm pointing at the gallery slider below it.

Answer (score 1):

for code sample that showed in your sent link

```
    <li class="design">
          <div class="icon">Design</div>
         <a href="http://www.studiopress.com/get-started" target="_blank"                class="info"><p>The Genesis design framework, support and dozens of stunning themes.</p><div class="btn-primary-small">Find Out More</div></a>
    </li>
```

the css will be

```
li.design a{
 display:none;
}
li.design:hover a{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: I got that far, but that doesn't explain what I need to know. What you provided doesn't act the same way as I described. That's why I'm asking for an example that acts the same way - not the same code.
Thanks for your response though.

Comment: You're not really going to get a transition with `display: none;` to `display: block;`   -  So you can use jQuery or opacity and CSS transitions, depending on the scenario. You could fade out the top layer to reveal the under layer - or have the top later fade in --- it depends on how important being able to select text is to you.